# Laravel 5.3 local storage path

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have Laravel 5.3 with local filesystem. The APP_URL in my .env is:

```
http://localhost/myapp
```

I linked the storage to public

```
php artisan storage:link
```

I have an image in:

```
myapp/storage/app/public/defaults/test/file.png
```

In the database the path is saved like this:

```
public/defaults/test/file.png
```

So in my blade.php I try to access the image

```
<img src="{{ Storage::url($user->test)}}" width="" alt="">
```

But the image isn't showing and the URL of the image is:

```
http://localhost/storage/defaults/test/file.png
```

so why it's ignoring the app_url? and even if i change the link to this:

```
http://localhost/myapp/storage/defaults/test/file.png
```

the image isn't showing up.

How can I access the Image in my myapp/storage/app/public/defaults/test/file.png with Storage::url?

BR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

1) Fire `php artisan storage:link` command, if you haven't already

2) In database, store path relative to the **root/public** directory with prefix **storage**.

So if you have image at root/public/defaults/test/file.png, then in the database, store this path: storage/defaults/test/file.png

3) And finally in the view, display it like:

```
<img src="{{ asset($user->test )}}" width="" alt="">
```

Make sure $user->test has value storage/defaults/test/file.png

**OR**

3) If you don't want to store **storage** prefix into the database, then store path like:

defaults/test/file.png

and in view:

```
<img src="{{ asset('storage/' . $user->test )}}" width="" alt="">
```

**Note:**
Tested with Laravel 5.4, but pretty sure that it will work for Laravel 5.3 as well.

---

Here is a complete demo that I have created which illustrates image uploading and displaying:

https://github.com/xparthx/laravel5.4-image-upload

Comment: I linked storage and in my DB is: storage/defaults/test/file.png
the physical file is here: root/storage/app/public/defaults/test/file.png and I show the image like `<img src="{{ asset($user->test )}}" width="" alt="">` everything good. 
But if I upload a new file with: `'image' => $r->image->store('storage/defaults/test')` - the DB is correct, but the file is saved here: root/storage/app/storage/defaults/test/file.png so the image dosn't showing up because it's in the wrong folder. How can I change the upload path but not the db path? Or why it's wrong?

Comment: Try to upload like this:
'image' => $r->image->store('defaults/test')

Comment: @blubbering, here is a complete demo that I have created which illustrates image uploading and displaying: https://github.com/xparthx/laravel5.4-image-upload

Answer (score 3):

if you want to access file in your storage folder you need to create route for that link

```
Route::get('storage/defaults/test/{filename}', function ($filename)
{
    $imagePath = storage_path() . '/defaults/test/' . $filename;

    if(!File::exists($imagePath)) {
        //Not have file do something here
    };

    $file = File::get($imagePath);
    $type = File::mimeType($path);

    $response = Response::make($file, 200);
    $response->header("Content-Type", $type);

    return $response;
});
```

now you can access by your link

You have another way such as keep your image in [your project]/public/images/ in this way you can access your image by http://localhost/images/file.png (no need to create route)

But I suggest your create a new folder in you server example /data/images
and set vhost in apache for allow the path

```
Alias /images /var/www/data/images

<Directory /var/www/data/images>
   IndexOptions FancyIndexing FoldersFirst
   Options MultiViews Indexes
   AllowOverride None
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Hope this help